# Does "insist" have special meaning in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I'm translating a book about women for a male client. The book is named "The Manual: What Women Want and How to Give It to Them" and I will give it to him this week. My client is very picky, so I must translate correctly with a high level of precision and attention to detail.

I have a confusing paragraph:

> [image: paragraph]

The writer is talking about the necessity of persistence when pursuing women.
I think that saying:

> When you ask for a woman’s number, insist that she give it to you even if she says that she cannot

is not good example, because if I "insist she give it to me even if she says that she cannot", she will reject me, so I will "cling on forever, stalk, or come back her", which conflicts with the previous opinion "to persist does not mean to cling on forever, to stalk, or to come back despite a woman requesting otherwise".

So why does the writer use this example in the paragraph? Or does "insist" have a special meaning?

Comment: Well, it's very clear for me, the writter is telling the readers to insist in asking her number even if she cannot, what did you not get in this paragraph? It seems to be very clear, see: 

_Even if she doesn't give you her number, insist! After 5 minutes she will give it to you._

_She is a very hard woman, but if you insist, she will for sure open herself to you._

**Insist**: _to say firmly or demand forcefully, especially when others disagree with or oppose what you say._

[link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/insist)

Comment: Folks please keep in mind that even though you might find the source material objectionable, the question here is about the strength of the word "insist" in this context and not whether or not this is good advice.

Comment: Did you look up the word "insist" in the dictionary?  Is there a reason that you think the dictionary definition doesn't apply here?

Comment: @Davyd Diniz, Rely on your explanation, i can understand that "she says that she cannot" does not mean "she reject me", right? She is only putting up resistance for me, right?

Comment: @chingliz in this context, the writer is advising his readers to insist on asking her number, if even she doesn't want to, I guess he meant that your attempts will end up in good results, maybe he is trying to say that women most part want to appear to be hard, and if you insist, she will probably hand it over to you

Comment: @chingliz So yeah, she may be just trying to put up resistance for you, but cpmsidering your attempts, she may hand it over to you, I guess that's what the author meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific example, I do not think the author's advice to insist that a woman gives you her phone number even though she says she cannot is in conflict with the description of persistence in the paragraph above.

As I read it, the author is quite clear on the limitations of any persistence in this context:

> [to persist] does mean to keep going until you either get what you want **or are rejected**.

*(emphasis mine)*

So there is some level of rejection which the author accepts should result in giving up. So when it is then stated to insist that a woman gives you her phone number even though she may have initially said she couldn't, the implication as I read it is that you just shouldn't give up right away (and instead, insist), but that eventually her rejection will be sufficiently complete that you should give up, as per the first paragraph.